# Ubuntu dolphin add a "create archive" option to menu

Tags: 14.04, dolphin, context-menu

Is there an easy way of creating a "create archive" item to the context menu of dolphin (like the one, that can be added to thunar or nautilus)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to

```
~/.kde/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus
```

Add a new file:

```
createArchive.desktop
```

Paste the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
X-KDE-ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
Actions=createAnArchive
MimeType=all/all

[Desktop Action createMyArchive]
Name=Create Archive...
Exec=file-roller --add %U
```

Restart Dolphin: close all instances (and eventually open again)
You might now check, if you successfully added that entry:

```
Open dolphin -> Settings -> Configure Dolphin -> Services -> [check, If the list contains
```

"Create Archive...". Also make sure it's checked]

Now you should be able to see the following entry:

```
Dolphin -> Context Menu -> Actions -> Create Archive
```

---

**explanation:**

```
MimeType=all/all
```

"all/all" makes sure, that the item will appear for any selected file, you use

```
Actions=createAnArchive
```

The action specified here must be the same as in

```
[Desktop Action createMyArchive]
```

This is the action, that will be called

```
Exec=file-roller --add %U
```

File-roller is the archive-program
%U will make invoke ONE instance of file-roller with ALL the selected files as parameters.
If you use %F here, you will invoke ONE instance PER selected item - which is probably not, 
what you want.

You might also want to check out the dir

```
/usr/share/mime/
```

to see further mimetypes, in order you want to restrict it more

Comment: unfortunately, this doesnt seem to work in ubuntu. there is no `ServiceMenus` under `services`, and even with creating this folder, no luck. edit:  `/usr/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus` seems to be the right folder.